# Draw a circle and blur line using Stroke in Ink Presenter

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, drawing, blur

I am able to increase or decrease the size of the Stroke, but now I want to blur the line or circle drawn by the Stroke on the Ink presenter.

So far I've tried:

```
drawingCanvas.CaptureMouse(); _colorStroke = new Stroke();
_colorStroke.StylusPoints.Add(GetStylusPoint(e.GetPosition(drawingCanvas)));
_colorStroke.DrawingAttributes.Color = colorPicked.Color;
_colorStroke.DrawingAttributes.Height= drawingCanvas.Strokes.Add(_colorStroke);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's bad etiquette to post a question without showing a reasonable amount of prior effort.

Comment: are you making app for Windows Phone 8 ? if yes check this app http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/doodle-draw/6eb00245-d36d-4a16-82dc-8205b6904484 it has some imlementation using stroke. You got some idea.

Comment: Ok, I've edited your code into your question. For future reference please edit your questions with updated code and details instead of putting them into comments.